# Using promises in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using webdriverJS to do some automated testing in chrome.

I'm currently waiting for an element to be displayed on a webpage before clicking it, although the issue I'm having is the element takes a few seconds to display before being clickable, so I need the driver to sleep for a few seconds before clicking the element. I was wondering how I could use promises with webdriverJS to achieve this.

```
return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('elementName')), 5000)
.then(element => {
  driver.sleep(2000);
  element.click();
});
```

Since javascript is asynchronous the element is trying to be clicked before the sleep so I was wondering how I can incorporate promises in webdriverJS so that the click only happens after the sleep has finished.

Comment: `driver.sleep(2000).then(()=>element.click());`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [webdriver documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html), the sleep method returns a promise which is resolved when the time is reached.

You can handle the asynchronous part with this code :

```
let element
return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('elementName')), 5000)
 .then(_element => { 
   element = _element
   return driver.sleep(2000)
  })
 .then(() => element.click())
```

With the async/await feature :

```
const func = async driver => {
  const element = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('elementName')), 5000)
  await driver.sleep(2000)
  element.click()
}
```

Comment: that's ugly complicated code. why not chain a `then` on  `sleep` directly?

Comment: The element reference is used after. I avoid to use then in then, to keep one level of promise.